# Change pitch of an audio file and save it with NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I found the NAudio library and I've read that it can change the pitch of an audio file while it is playing, but I want to change the pitch of the audio file and then save it. Is it possible with NAudio?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `SmbPitchShiftingSampleProvider` which is a managed pitch shifter.

You could read the input audio with `AudioFileReader`, pass it into `SmbPitchShiftingSampleProvider` setting the `PitchFactor` and then using `WaveFile.CreateWaveFile16` to write the pitch shifted file out to a 16 bit PCM WAV File.